# Docker Container containing ReactJS App is running locally but fails on Webserver

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, production

When running the command:

docker run -p 80:3200 greenandeasy-website

in webservers ssh terminal the following error ist droped:

> greenandeasy-webapp@0.1.0 start /greenandeasy-website
>   node ./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start

module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

```
Error: Cannot find module '/greenandeasy- 
website/node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! greenandeasy-webapp@0.1.0 start: `node 
./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the greenandeasy-webapp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely . 
additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did 
you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-09-05T21_00_36_494Z-debug.log
```

I understand that it is not finding a react-scripts.js but i wonder why the exact same commands do work on local maschine and not on the server.

Thank you for some ideas to resolve this problem ;)

dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6-wheezy

WORKDIR /src/green-and-easy/

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

ENV NODE_JS_PORT=80

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: There's an absolute file path in both the error message and the start command that doesn't match what's in your Dockerfile.  Is it hard-coded in a `"start"` command in your package.json, or something like that?

Comment: "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

Comment: This is my package.json start section